# Multiple db inserts with Django performance is not increased by parallel threads

Tags: django, postgresql

I'm doing thousands and thousands of inserts to a PostgreSQL database with Python and Django (using the CLI, so no web server at all).
The objects that are inserted are already in memory, and I'm poping them one by one from a FIFO queue (using Python's native https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html)

What I'm doing basically is:

```
args1, args2 = queue.get()
m1, _ = Model1.objects.get_or_create(args1)
Model2.objects.create(m1, args2)
```

I was thinking a way to do this faster was too spawn a few more threads that can do this in parallel. To my surprise the performance is actually slightly decreased... I was expecting almost linear improvement in relation to the number of threads.. not sure what's going on..

Is there something database specific I'm missing, are there table locks that are blocking the threads when this is running?
Or does it have something to do with that each thread can only access a single database connection atomically during runtime?

I have standard configuration for PostgreSQL (9.3) and Django (1.7.7) installed with apt-get on Debian Jessie.
Also I tried with 4 threads, which is the same number of CPUs I have available on my box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few things going on here.

Firstly you are using very high level ORM methods (`get_or_create`, `create`). Those are generally not a good fit for bulk operations since methods like that tend to have a lot of overhead to provide a nice API and also do additional work to prevent users from shooting themselves in the foot too easily.

Secondly your careful use of a `queue` is very counterproductive in multiple ways:

- Due to django running in [autocommit mode](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/transactions/) by default each database operation is carried out in its own transaction. Since that is a relatively expensive operation this also causes unnecessary overhead.
- Inserting each object by itself also causes a lot more back and forth communication between the database and django, which again produces overhead, slowing things down.

Thirdly the reason using multiple threads is even slower stems from the fact that python has a GIL (Global Interpreter Lock). This prevents multiple threads from executing Python code at the same time. There is a lot of material on the web about the whys and hows of the GIL and what can be done in which circumstances to mitigate it. There is a nice [summary by Dave Beazly](http://www.dabeaz.com/python/UnderstandingGIL.pdf) about the GIL that should get you started if you're interested in learning more about it.

Additionally I'd generally recommend against doing large inserts from multiple threads in any language since - depending on your database and data model - this can also cause slowdowns inside the database due to possibly required locking.

Now there are many solutions to your problem but I'd recommend to start with a simple one: 
Django actually provides a handy low-level interface to create models in bulk, fittingly enough called [`bulk_create()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.bulk_create). I'd suggest removing all that fancy queue and thread code and using this interface as directly as possible with the data you already have.

In case this isn't sufficient for your case a possible alternative would be to generate an `INSERT INTO` statement from the data and executing that directly on the database.

Answer (score 2):

If all you want to achieve is simply insertion, could you instead just use the `save()` method instead of `get_or_create()`. `get_or_create()` queries the database first. If the table is large, the call to `get_or_create()` can be a bottleneck. And that's probably why having multiple parallel threads do not help.

The other possibility is with the insertion itself. Postgres by default enables *auto-commit* on a per insert (transaction) basis. The committing process involves complex mechanisms under the hood. Long story short, you may try disabling auto-commit and see if that would help in your particular case. A relevant article is [here](http://thebuild.com/blog/2009/11/07/django-postgresql-and-autocommit/).